# ORA-00942 error when referencing table after EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create table

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I try to run the following snippet in PL/SQL Developer, but the last command throws an **ORA-00942: table or view does not exist** error message.

```
DECLARE 
    sqlCommandABC varchar2(30000) := 'create table ABC_TMP
        tablespace &TBS_NORMAL_TABLES initrans 32 AS (SELECT ABC_ID from ABC where ID <=400000)';
BEGIN   
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ABC_TMP';
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
    END;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlCommandABC;
    COMMIT;
END;
/

DECLARE
    sqlCommandDEF varchar2(30000) := 'create table DEF_TMP
        tablespace &TBS_NORMAL_TABLES initrans 32 AS (SELECT DEF_ID from DEF where ID <=15000)';
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE DEF_TMP';
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
    END;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlCommandDEF;
    COMMIT;
END;
/


DECLARE
    sqlCommandXYZ varchar2(30000) := 'create table XYZ_TMP
        tablespace &TBS_NORMAL_TABLES initrans 32 AS (select ID from XYZ where ABC_1 in (SELECT ABC_ID from ABC_TMP) or DEF_1 in (SELECT DEF_ID from DEF_TMP))';
BEGIN   
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE XYZ_TMP';
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
    END;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlCommandXYZ;
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I want to create two temporary tables by selecting data from the original table, with some condition according to the logic.

After the **ABC_TMP** and the **DEF_TMP** created, I need to use them in a condition for the select of the third temporary table.

The **XYZ_TMP** table has two conditions, one for the ABC_TMP records and another for the DEF_TMP records. 
This third create table clause throws the error.

I know i could use the original selects here, but those are pretty complex and has a relatively high cost, so if it is possible i want to use the filtered tables. I also know that if I open a new session after the first two tables created it will work, but I want to execute these in one script.

Comment: So maybe XYZ  table does not exist?

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake in the code, i edited it.

Comment: @KaushikNayak the error rejecting statement refers to the DROP TABLE (eg: if the table not exists, then it throws an error), i don't think it is the root cause.

Comment: Ok..my bad I didn't notice correctly. Are you sure the 2 temp tables are created before you run the last PL/SQL block? Have you checked it through normal(static) SQL? If yes, then it could be `GRANT` issue for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the provided info, I understood that DEF_TMP and ABC_TMP is successfully created and thus available. in that case, there are two possibilities here.

- First is XYZ table is not exists
- Second is the user trying to execute this command does not have select grant.